# When we use irq_set_chained_handler the irq line will be disabled or not?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, interrupt-handling, irq

When we use irq_set_chained_handler the irq line will not be disabled or not, when we are servicing the associated handler, as in case of request_irq.

Comment: It's continuation of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377846/what-is-chained-irq-in-linux-when-are-they-need-to-used) question.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter how the interrupt was setup. When any interrupt occurred, all interrupts (for this CPU) will be disabled during the interrupt handler. For example, on ARM architecture first place in C code where interrupt handling is found is `asm_do_IRQ()` function (defined in `arch/arm/kernel/irq.c`). It's being called from assembler code. For any interrupt (whether it was requested by `request_irq()` or by `irq_set_chained_handler()`) the same `asm_do_IRQ()` function is called, and interrupts are disabled automatically by ARM CPU. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295403/should-my-interrupt-handler-disable-interrupts-or-does-the-arm-processor-do-it-a) for details.

### Historical notes

Also, it worth to be mentioned that some time ago Linux kernel was providing two types of interrupts: "fast" and "slow" ones. Fast interrupts (when using `IRQF_DISABLED` or `SA_INTERRUPT` flag) were running with disabled interrupts, and those handlers supposed to be very short and quick. Slow interrupts, on the other hand, were running with re-enabled interrupts, because handlers for slow interrupts may take much of time to be handled.

On modern versions of Linux kernel all interrupts are considered as "fast" and are running with interrupts disabled. Interrupts with huge handlers must be implemented as threaded (or enable interrupts manually in ISR using `local_irq_enable_in_hardirq()`).

That behavior was changed in Linux kernel v2.6.35 by [this](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/commit/?id=6932bf37bed45ce8ed531928b1b0f98162fe6df6) commit. You can find more details about this [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/380931/).

Answer (score 3):

Refer https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/driver.txt

> This means the GPIO irqchip is registered using
>   irq_set_chained_handler() or the corresponding
>   gpiochip_set_chained_irqchip() helper function, and the GPIO irqchip
>   handler will be called immediately from the parent irqchip, while
>   holding the IRQs disabled. The GPIO irqchip will then end up calling
>   something like this sequence in its interrupt handler: